# Can't trace hinted handoff in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to emulate hinted handoff using Cassandra cluster in Docker.

Hinted handoff is active:

```
root@2f5aa8d649e2:/# nodetool statushandoff
Hinted handoff is running
```

The keyspace has a replication factor of 3:

```
cqlsh> DESCRIBE  KEYSPACE imdb;
CREATE KEYSPACE imdb WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1': '2', 'dc2': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

Then I shut one node down, turn on tracing and insert a new row:

```
cqlsh:imdb> insert into movies_by_actor (actor, movie_id, character, movie_title, salary) values ('TomHanks', uuid(), 'Character', 'Title', 1000);

Tracing session: e4a2cc20-42ce-11e7-bd49-cf534e0135c6

 activity                                                                                                                                                                     | timestamp                  | source     | source_elapsed | client
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+-----------
                                                                                                                                                           Execute CQL3 query | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.466000 | 172.13.0.2 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
 Parsing insert into movies_by_actor (actor, movie_id, character, movie_title, salary) values ('TomHanks', uuid(), 'Character', 'Title', 1000); [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.467000 | 172.13.0.2 |            364 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                            Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.467000 | 172.13.0.2 |            727 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                              Determining replicas for mutation [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.468000 | 172.13.0.2 |           1354 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Sending MUTATION message to /172.13.0.3 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.13.0.3-Small] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.468000 | 172.13.0.2 |           1722 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                        Sending MUTATION message to /172.13.0.6 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.13.0.6-Small] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.468000 | 172.13.0.2 |           1722 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           MUTATION message received from /172.13.0.2 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.13.0.2] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.3 |             30 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                           MUTATION message received from /172.13.0.2 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.13.0.2] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.6 |             35 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                                     Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.3 |            294 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                                     Appending to commitlog [MutationStage-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.6 |            292 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                         Adding to movies_by_actor memtable [MutationStage-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.6 |            486 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                          Enqueuing response to /172.13.0.2 [MutationStage-1] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469000 | 172.13.0.6 |            660 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                   REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /172.13.0.3 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.13.0.3] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.470000 | 172.13.0.2 |           3659 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                Processing response from /172.13.0.3 [RequestResponseStage-2] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.470000 | 172.13.0.2 |           3820 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                Sending REQUEST_RESPONSE message to /172.13.0.2 [MessagingService-Outgoing-/172.13.0.2-Small] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.472000 | 172.13.0.6 |           3533 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                   REQUEST_RESPONSE message received from /172.13.0.6 [MessagingService-Incoming-/172.13.0.6] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.473000 | 172.13.0.2 |             34 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                Processing response from /172.13.0.6 [RequestResponseStage-3] | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.473000 | 172.13.0.2 |            523 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                                                                                                             Request complete | 2017-05-27 11:23:22.469919 | 172.13.0.2 |           3919 | 127.0.0.1
```

As seen from the log, coordinator node `172.13.0.2` processes the request and contacts nodes `172.13.0.3` and `172.13.0.6`. I would expect node `172.13.0.2` to save a hinted handoff, since the third node is unavailable. But when I check the `system.hints` table, it is empty:

```
cqlsh:imdb> select * from system.hints;

 target_id | hint_id | message_version | mutation
-----------+---------+-----------------+----------

(0 rows)
```

The consistency level is set to default `ONE`. Could someone explain where the hinted handoff is stored, if at all?

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of cassandra does not store hints in `system.hints` table.

Hints are stored in flat files from cassandra 3.0. If using cassandra version greater than 3.0 you must look into hints directory configured in `cassandra.yaml`

```
# Directory where Cassandra should store hints. 
# If not set, the default directory is $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/hints. 
hints_directory: "C:/Program Files/DataStax-DDC/data/hints" 
# How often hints should be flushed from the internal buffers to disk. 
# Will *not* trigger fsync. 
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000
```

Check above 2 values in your `cassandra.yaml` and look for hints in it.

[Hinted Handoff in cassandra 3.0](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-coming-to-cassandra-in-3-0-improved-hint-storage-and-delivery)